# asp.net c# using sqlite with entity framework edited

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I most likely have some very basic beginner questions but right now they leave me very confused.

Background information: I need too create a simple asp.net application using the c# language. This application needs too store and retrieve data from a sqlite database using the entity framework.

So naturally I created a asp.net c# Web Application in my Visual Studio 2010, I removed all the unnecessary stuff. Then I installed everything I needed for sqlite and added the references too the project, same goes for Entity Framework.

- Language: C# / ASP.net
- Database type: SQLite.
- Entity Framework 4.1
- Environment: Visual Studio 2010
- Project location: `C:\Users\<User name>\Desktop\<Project name>`
- Database location: `C:\Users\<User name>\Desktop\<Project name>\<Project name>\database.db`

My questions:

Okay I have followed this tutorial 'bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html'.

I used the

```
<system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
   <add name="SQLite Data Provider"
      invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
      description="Data Provider for SQLite"
      type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
   </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

and

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB"
    connectionString= "Data Source=|DataDirectory|database.db"
    providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
</connectionStrings>
```

in my web config file but it's trowing a error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.data: Column 'InvariantName' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'System.Data.SQLite' is already present.

```
Source Error:


Line 10:   </configSections>
Line 11:   
Line 12:   <system.data>
Line 13:     <DbProviderFactories>
Line 14:       <add name="SQLite Data Provider"


Source File: C:\Users\<User name>\Desktop\<Project name>\<Project name>\web.config    Line: 12
```

But the thing is 'System.Data.SQLite' is first defined there... or atleast in this file.
I really don't know why it's behaving like this and I could really use some help.

I'm very gratefull for your help and hope too get a answer soon.

Comment: did you try a beginner tutorial first? http://www.bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html

Comment: @balexandre I have been trying too find one but was unable too. Thank you for this, it will no doubtedly help me.